# comparison does not allow me to act on the results

Tags: python, list, compare

I want to know why is it that my if statements are not working. I have code that compares a recently compiled list to a bunch of other lists to see if there is a similar one.

The lists are made up of 12 values, direction of the list, and the number of times that same list has occurred. the comparison is done between the first 12 values of each list then what should happen is the position that is found with that list should be identified, however it seems I am unable to call that into action.

In essence this is what I want to do...

These are the lists I want to compare to one another:

```
list1 = [['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 5], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 13], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 5], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 8], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 10], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 6], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 8], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 6], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 3], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 7], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 9], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 7], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1]]
list2 = ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

This is the comparison code I want to use for the lists:

```
def fl(list1, list2):
    index = -1
    occ = 0
    for i, l in enumerate(list2):
        if l[:len(list1)] == list1:
            if l[-1] > occ:
                index = i
                occ = l[-1]

    if index == -1:
        return "The first list is not present in the second one."
    else:
        print(f"The first lists appears in the second one at index {index} with a number of occurences equal too {occ}.")
        u = "up"
        y = "down"
        lp = [(''.join(a[:6]), a[6]) for a in list2]
        if (''.join(list1), u) in lp:
            print("up")

        elif (''.join(list1), y) in lp:
            print("down")

print(fl(listB, listA))
```

This is the result I want to get:

```
The first lists appears in the second one at index 2 with a number of occurrences equal to 2.
up
```

However what I seem too get is this:

```
The first lists appears in the second one at index 2 with a number of occurrences equal too 2.
None
```

Why am I getting `none` and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: `up` and `down` are not in `list2`. They're in `list1`, and at index `11`, not index `6`.

Comment: Use `print(lp)` to see what it contains, that will explain why you're not getting the expected results.

Comment: The function should either return something or print something. Doing both is confusing. You don't return anything in the `else` block, that's why it prints `None` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is caused in the if/elif statement. In general if/elif should be used ONLY when you know that you covered **ALL** possible scenarios in your code.

Comment: i still cant seem to figure out what the problem... please help me

Comment: Don't just describe the problem, show how to fix the code.

Comment: This answer would be better if you showed some code - currently it’s not really helpful